# Proof of non-prime Mersenne numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, induction

I have to prove that $2^n-1$ is not a prime number if $n$ wasn't a prime number.
I have done it.

If $n = 1$, then $2^n-1 = 1$. And if I write $2^{n+1}$, so $n+1$ will be the next non-prime number and that will be $4$. $2^4-1 = 15$. So far so good.

But when I am doing the induction I am wondering why this would be possible:

$2^{n+1} - 1 = 2^n * 2 - 1$

$16-1 = 2^1 * 2 -1 $

$15 = 3$

It's false for sure, but why?

Comment: For which value of $n$ are you verifying the equation $2^{n+1}-1=2^n2-1$? $16$ is $2^4$, not $2^2$.

Comment: I updated format and title - aMersenne number is one less than a power of $2$. Please check that I have not made a mistake in your meaning

Comment: Hint: $2^n-1=1+2+\ldots+2^{n-1}$. When can the right side be factored?

Comment: For your "proof", it is not true that if $n=1$, $n+1 = 4$. $4$ is the next non-prime after $1$ but it is not reached by adding one.

Comment: {=0}∑{-1} 2^k = 2^n-1 -- that's how I did it...But like @Joffan said, that it's not true that if n = 1, n+1 = 4. How can I then use say:

{=0}∑{} 2^k = 2^{n+1}-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof doesn't work as given. Actual proofs of this tend to be algebraic rather than inductive but you can potentially squeeze induction in there in various ways.

Let's prove a small well-known equality first:

**Claim:** $2^n-1 = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k$
Proof: By induction.
Base case $n=1$, with $2^1-1 = 1$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{0}2^k = 2^0 = 1$ as required.
Assume $2^n-1 = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k$, then $2^{n+1}-1 = 2^n+2^n-1 = 2^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^k$ as required.

Now observe that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k$ has $n$ terms. Assume that $n$ is composite and we have $n=ab$ with $a,b>1$.Then we can split this sum in $b$ parts of $a$ length:

$$\begin{align}
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
2^n-1 = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k &= \sum_{\ell=0}^{b-1}  \sum_{m=0}^{a-1} 2^{\large a\ell+m} \tag{groups of $a$}\\
  & = \sum_{\ell=0}^{b-1}  \sum_{m=0}^{a-1} \left(2^{\large a\ell}2^{\large m} \right)  \tag{separate exponent}\\
  & = \sum_{\ell=0}^{b-1} \left(2^{\large a\ell} \sum_{m=0}^{a-1} 2^{\large m} \right)  \tag{constant term}\\
  & = \left(\sum_{\ell=0}^{b-1} 2^{\large a\ell}\right) \left(\sum_{m=0}^{a-1} 2^{\large m} \right) \tag{independent sums}\\
\end{align}$$

Now since $a,b>1$, both of these factors are also greater than one and $2^n-1$ is composite when $n$ is composite.

The other non-prime case, $n=1$, gives $2^n-1=1$ and that is also not prime.

Comment: Thanks @Joffan! Since we just used the induction to for proofs I didn’t know that I can prove It in that Way. I also wouldn’t take into consideration that n is a composite number while looking for the result even if it is clearly because it’s a non-prime.

Comment: That's pretty much the heart of the proof. You could turn it round a bit to show that (for example) $2^{kn}-1$ is always a multiple of $2^n-1$. Same idea though.

Comment: Thank you again, I accepted it 